# Deploy.jar does not work with Java 7

Tags: java, jar, java-7

I have an application built in Java SE 6 and I use the jar deploy.jar to get the proxy definitions on browser to my Application.
In Java 6 the following code works well, but in Java 7 the same code does not work.
NOTE: I changed the Deploy Jar for the jar that comes with JRE 7 and it still doesn't work

```
    BrowserProxyInfo browseProxyInfo = new BrowserProxyInfo();
browseProxyInfo.setAutoConfigURL(autoConfigURL);
browseProxyInfo.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
    WIExplorerAutoProxyHandler wHandler = new WIExplorerAutoProxyHandler();
wHandler.init(browseProxyInfo);
    URL url = new URL(ConfigLoader.WS_URL + "atualizacao?wsdl");
com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyInfo[] proxyInfos = wHandler.getProxyInfo(url);
```

Comment: DO you get any error or exception?

Comment: Deploy.jar is a Jar that comes with JRE e I use to get the Proxy Settings on Windows.

Comment: I get NullPointer in proxyInfos variable

Answer (score 0):

Is this an official API? Probably, not.

Try to get the information via the java.net-package. Maybe [ProxySelector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html)? (I haven't tried.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the user profile in order for it to work in JAVA 7.

```
sun.plugin.util.UserProfile

new UserProfile();
```